# RPM subpackage name

Tags: rpm

Is it possible to make a subpackage without the inherited prefix from the master package?

I have a project that has a single install and need to split this into multiple packages, but the subpackages seem to inherit the name from the master package in the form of "package_name-subpackage_name".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Use `%package -n subpackage`; this will suppress the prepending of the base package name.

This is all pretty clear in the [RPM docs](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-subpack-spec-file-changes.html).

Comment: Thanks. I still have a problem though, the build still creates the top package, how do I stop this?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be I don't remember offhand if you can even do that. I suggest not worrying about it; either generate the empty package and just don't install it, or (better, I think) use it to install some simple documentation about the collection of subpackages.